# Simulating heteroscedacticity

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to simulate a simple regression model with varying degree of heteroscedacticity. I want to make a simple simulation that shows how increasing heteroscedacticity affects various parts of the model (coefficients vs standard errors etc.). Here is the code so far:

```
N <- 1e4
x <- rnorm(N, 10, 1)

results <- data.frame(i = numeric(),
                      beta = numeric(),
                      se = numeric(),
                      var_y = numeric())

for (i in 1:100) {
  y <- rnorm(N,.7*x, i/x)
  
  fit <- lm(y ~ x)
  r <- c(i = i, beta = coef(fit)[[2]], se = summary(fit)$coefficients[, 2][[2]], var_y = var(y))
  results <- rbind(results, r)
}

colnames(results) <- c("i", "beta", "se", "var_y")
plot(results$beta)
plot(results$se)
plot(results$var_y)
```

The problem is that I'm worried I'm not only introducing heteroscedacticity but also increasing overall variance in y which itself is going to affect the model results.

Is there some way to increase the amount of heteroscedacticity without changing anything else?
Am i overthinking this and standardizing y inside the model (so running `lm(scale(y) ~ x)`) will be enough?

Comment: How are you determining "too much variance"? In my head, heteroskedasticity has to do with that variability of the variance, not with the scale of it. If you think your overall variance is too high (regardless of hetero...), decrease it in your call to `rnorm` while still preserving the changed variance.

Comment: My point is that I want the overall variance in y to stay constant across each run of the loop. To put it more graphically if you were to make scatterplots of the data I want to get a gradually increasingly wide cone but without changing overall variance in y. Basically I want to manipulate the degree of heteroscadicticity while keeping everything else in the model the same. Or is that just not feasible?

Comment: I understand what you mean. The unconditional variance in y is the variance in the conditional mean of y plus the mean of the conditional variance (i.e. the mean of the error variance). So to compare with homoscedasticity, you need not only to widen the cone at one end but to narrow it at the other in such a way that the total error variance remains constant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
n <- 1e4

set.seed(42)
x <- runif(n, 0, 100)
sd <- 0.1
y1 <- 10 + 0.1 * x + rnorm(n, sd = sd)

var(y1)
#[1] 8.458331

summary(mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x))
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 1.000e+01  1.996e-03    5010   <2e-16 ***
# x           9.998e-02  3.456e-05    2892   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.1005 on 9998 degrees of freedom


const <- 0.5
power <- 2

#this is the function from nlme::varConstPower, other functions are possible, e.g., help("varClasses", package = "nlme)
var2 <- (const + abs(x)^power)^2
var2 <- var2/mean(var2) * sd^2
y2 <- 10 + 0.1 * x + rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(var2))

var(y2)
#[1] 8.46444
#Note that this derived from the sample. 
#You should care more about the true variance (or the residual standard error below)


summary(mod20 <- lm(y2 ~ x))
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 1.000e+01  2.006e-03    4984   <2e-16 ***
# x           1.000e-01  3.474e-05    2879   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.101 on 9998 degrees of freedom

library(nlme)
summary(mod21 <- gls(y2 ~ x, weights = varConstPower(form = ~ x)))
#     const     power 
# 0.4123067 1.9807457 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                 Value    Std.Error t-value p-value
# (Intercept) 10.000000 1.750794e-06 5711695       0
# x            0.100003 2.755056e-06   36298       0
```